# CSS Circle at start of Horizontal rule missing in IE and Edge

Tags: css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I want to put a coloured circle at the left side of horizontal rule.

Below is what I have used to display a circle at the beginning of a horizontal rule. It works in all modern browsers except IE 11 and Edge. I have tried everything I can think of and search endlessly. Can anyone help?

```
.leftArticle hr:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #4990cd;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont use pseudoelements with `hr`.

```css
.leftArticle {
  position: relative;
}
.leftArticle:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: #4990cd;
  margin-top: -7px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftArticle">
  <hr>
</div>
```

Display issues:

```css
hr {
  height: .9em;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: pink;
}
hr::before {
  content: 'demo of this problem';
}
```

```html
<hr>
```